# How can I create RDLC to display for 2 tables with different condition by using 1 dataset

Tags: datatable, header, report, grouping, rdlc

All data will show in the first table, another table will be shown only the tax A/C.
For example,

1st table:

```
Row 1  AC 1000   amount 1000  non Tax AC
Row 2  AC 2000   amount    3  Tax AC
Row 3  AC 3000   amount 3000  non Tax AC
Row 4  AC 2000   amount    9  Tax AC
Row 5  AC 1111   amount 4012  non Tax AC
```

2nd table:

```
Row 1  AC 2000   amount    3  Tax AC
Row 2  AC 2000   amount    9  Tax AC
```

I try to ask ChatGPT and also find the tutorial clip on Youtube but I cannot get it.